# Add a dynamically created element to a REST API in Springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to create a database that will hold the prices of assets that are obtained from exchanges.  I've created an Exchange class that holds variables that are the various prices.  In my code, I have the following:

```
 try{
        Exchange Coinbase = new Exchange();
        Coinbase.setName("Coinbase");
        Coinbase.setBtcBuy(priceRequestCoinbase(btcBuy));
        Coinbase.setBtcSell(priceRequestCoinbase(btcSell));
        Coinbase.setEthBuy(priceRequestCoinbase(ethBuy));
        Coinbase.setEthSell(priceRequestCoinbase(ethSell));
```

I am now just struggling to figure out how I would add this to my database so that it is accessible through api calls later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert this as a json string using objectmapper and store as text / json in your DB. The api can return this and directly convert to your exchange object.
Adding:
Better way would be to have an exchange table with your field names as columns. Create a repository class implementing jparepository for your exchange object. Annotate your exchange object with @entity annotation and autogenerated Id. Use the inbuilt jpa save method to save to db.

Also by Java standards the variable names should start with a lowercase (coinbase)

Comment: Thank you.  So I would be able to convert the coinbase object into a string doing something like String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(Coinbase);?  And this call would be done after all those sets yeah? Also then how would I actually save it into the db?

Comment: The right way would be to have an exchange table with the fields as columns. Then you wouldn't have to convert to string or anything just use a jpa repository to save your object to db. If that's not feasible and the entire object needs to be saved as a whole then you can save it to a text column in db as a json string. Better is the first way.

Comment: I would suggest you do this. Take a look at Spring Data JPA (https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa and https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa) so that you can map a relational database to your Java entities.